# NetSuite Web Services API - How to “partially” fulfil a sales order 2

Tags: c#, netsuite

I'm trying to partially fulfill an order in netsuite (Web services API). Here is the simplest code that I came up with after reading the NetSuiteWebServicesRecordsGuide_2_5_0.pdf. No matter what I do, the order gets always completely fulfilled. Here is the simplest code I came up with,

Trying to fulfill the first item of three in an order:

```
            var ifi = new ItemFulfillmentItem()
            {
                orderLine = 1,  //  For the fist item in the list
                orderLineSpecified = true,
                quantity = 1.0,
                quantitySpecified = true
            };
            var itemFulfillment = new ItemFulfillment() { 
                createdFrom = new RecordRef() { internalId = MySalesOrderInternalId.internalId, type = RecordType.salesOrder, typeSpecified = true },
                itemList = new ItemFulfillmentItemList(){ item = new ItemFulfillmentItem[] { ifi } , replaceAll = false}
            };
            var result = _service.add(itemFulfillment);
```

Answer (score 2):

All lines must be present and when you only include some NetSuite will include the others in the fulfillment for their full quantity.  Include the lines you don't want with a 0 quantity an itemIsFulfilled to false.

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer stating that the quantity must be 0 and the itemIsFulfilled must be set to false it worked for me using SOAP and it was able to accommodate partially fulfilled item lines. Below is the XML that worked for me. Additionally, if you will only fulfill a specific number of quantity the itemIsFulfilled would still be set to false but the quantity must be the quantity that you will be fulfilling.

```html
<add xsi:type='platformMsgs:AddRequest'>
            <record xsi:type='tranSales:ItemFulfillment'>
                <createdFrom xsi:type='platformCore:RecordRef' internalId='22603' type='salesOrder'/>
                <itemList replaceAll='false' xsi:type='tranSales:ItemFulfillmentItemList'>
                    <item xsi:type='tranSales:ItemFulfillmentItem'>
                        <quantity xsi:type='xsd:double'>1</quantity>
                        <item xsi:type='platformCore:RecordRef' internalId='251'/>
                        <orderLine xsi:type='xsd:long'>1</orderLine>
                        <itemIsFulfilled xsi:type='xsd:boolean'>true</itemIsFulfilled>
                    </item>
                    <item xsi:type='tranSales:ItemFulfillmentItem'>
                        <quantity xsi:type='xsd:double'>0</quantity>
                        <item xsi:type='platformCore:RecordRef' internalId='47'/>
                        <orderLine xsi:type='xsd:long'>2</orderLine>
                        <itemIsFulfilled xsi:type='xsd:boolean'>false</itemIsFulfilled>
                    </item>
                </itemList>
            </record>
        </add>
```